# Delphi Library Memory Manager Strange

Tags: c++, delphi, dll

I got an error from DLL that compiled from Delphi using in c++ run in multithread

Delphi (Architect 10.3 Version 26.0.32429.4364) Library Code

```
library Project1;

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes;

{$R *.res}

procedure __test(size: integer); cdecl;
var
  data : AnsiString;
begin
  SetLength(data, size);
end;

exports
  __test;

begin
end.
```

C++ (Viausl Studio 2019) Load Library And Using Multithread

```
// ConsoleApplication1.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <thread>

typedef void(__cdecl *functest)(int);

HINSTANCE hInst = nullptr;

functest test;

void thread_loop() {
    while (1) {
        test(10);
    }
}

int main()
{
    hInst = LoadLibraryA("Project1.dll");

    if (!hInst) {
        return 0;
    }

    test = (functest)GetProcAddress(hInst, "__test");

    if (!test) {
        return 0;
    }

    std::thread t1(thread_loop);
    std::thread t2(thread_loop);

    return 1;
```

I got an exception but it should not get any exception because that is procedure variable which was not shared

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set [`IsMultiThread`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.IsMultiThread) to `True` in your Delphi DLL's main block. Delphi's default memory manager assumes single-threaded mode by default.

```
begin
  IsMultiThread := True;
end.
```